# Correct layout for ViewPager and FAB?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

If I wanted a `ViewPager` with several `Fragments`, and a `FloatingActionButton` that is used by one one of those `Fragments`, what would be the ideal layout behavior?

A. Should the `FAB` be located in the `Activity` layout, which also contains the `CoordinatorLayout` holding the `AppBarLayout`/`Toolbar`/`ViewPager`?

or

B. Should the `FAB` be located in the `Fragment` layout?

Option A makes sense in that the `FAB` should be able to animate as necessary within the `CoordinatorLayout`.  For example, if I show a `Snackbar`, I'd like to the `FAB` to shift up/down with the showing/hiding of the `Snackbar`.  However, placing the `FAB` here requires me to hide/show the `FAB` as necessary, since the other two `Fragments` will not be using the `FAB` and should have it hidden.

Option B is essentially the inverse of these benefits/drawbacks.

What is more correct?

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: There isn't a correct answer to this. It's up to you and can be different depending on your use-cases. (And for that reason this kind of question is considered off topic for StackOverflow as it tends to receive opinionated responses). Worst case scenario, try both and do what feels more natural.

Comment: Most design practices place `FAB` in the `activity` layout. It is easier to follow what is already done although you may have alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

> A. Should the **FAB** be located in the `Activity` layout, which also
>   contains the `CoordinatorLayout` holding the
>   `AppBarLayout/Toolbar/ViewPager`?

Yes, exactly.

**Look at this example:**

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppbarLayout/>
    <scrollableView/>
    <FloatingActionButton/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see, in the above example we used `FloatingActionButton` inside the `CoordinatorLayout` which that `FloatingActionButton` can be on the layout all the time without scrolling or even hiding after scrolling the `Fragment` or any views.

And finally, you can use this for your `Fragment`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also, let me mention that i've added that `FrameLayout` with `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` 
which can be under the `AppbarLayout`.

That's the point for that line.

> B. Should the FAB be located in the `Fragment` layout?

That depends on you but, Using it with `CoordinatorLayout` is the best way.i mean, you can achieve many **MaterialDesign** stuffs with it.